# (JavaFX) SplitPane.getDividerPositions() Inconsistent

Tags: javafx, splitpane

I have a `SplitPane` in my main GUI that is behaving strangely.  I am trying to save the position between executions of the program and do so by writing/reading a simple text file.

However, I am noticing that the `getPosition()` method returns an incorrect value when saving it to the file.

When exiting the program, I am saving the position with this code:

```
Settings.setSplitPaneLocation(Global.commentMasterController.getSplitPane().getDividers().get(0).getPosition());
```

- `Global` is a Singleton that holds references to my main GUI controllers.
- `Settings` is another Singleton that contains the values loaded from the settings file.

Upon loading the program, I set the position of the `SplitPane` by loading the last saved value from the `Settings` class:

```
splitPane.setDividerPosition(0, Settings.getSplitPaneLocation());
```

The problem is, when I load the program, even if I don't adjust the `SplitPane` position at all (load the program and immediately exit), the position that is saved is different from the position it was initially set to.

Here is the output, showing 3 consecutive runs of the program.  Again, this is just running the program and immediately exiting; I don't adjust the position of any controls at all:

```
setDividerPosition(): 0.9247730220492867
getDividerPosition(): 0.9105058365758755

setDividerPosition(): 0.9105058365758755
getDividerPosition(): 0.893644617380026

setDividerPosition(): 0.893644617380026
getDividerPosition(): 0.874189364461738
```

As you can see, `getDividerPosition()` returns a different value than the actual position of the divider.

I have checked the max/min sizes of the child nodes within the `SplitPane` and the min size is set to 0.

Answer (score 1):

From the [Javadocs for `SplitPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/SplitPane.html):

> A divider's position ranges from 0 to 1.0(inclusive). A position of 0
>   will place the divider at the left/top most edge of the SplitPane plus
>   the minimum size of the node. A position of 1.0 will place the divider
>   at the right/bottom most edge of the `SplitPane` minus the minimum
>   size of the node. A divider position of 0.5 will place the the divider
>   in the middle of the `SplitPane`. Setting the divider position greater
>   than the node's maximum size position will result in the divider being
>   set at the node's maximum size position. Setting the divider position
>   less than the node's minimum size position will result in the divider
>   being set at the node's minimum size position. *Therefore the value
>   set in `setDividerPosition(int, double)` and
>   `setDividerPositions(double...)` may not be the same as the value
>   returned by `getDividerPositions()`.*

(My emphasis.) Without knowing more about what you are doing, it is hard to be precise about the behavior you are observing, but I suspect that the value you are setting is being adjusted to account for the min/max sizes of the content nodes.

Comment: I updated my question with more detail/code.  I've checked the minimum size of the children and the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

*I've had a similar problem and found this post without a real solution, so maybe it helps someone in the future:*

Try to use `Platform.runLater()`. Apparently there's something clashing when you start an application and want to change GUI-elements at the same time.

For your specific question it would be:
`Platform.runLater(() -> splitPane.setDividerPosition(0, Settings.getSplitPaneLocation()));`

I've found this hint in the following blogpost: http://broadlyapplicable.blogspot.de/2015/03/javafx-capture-restore-splitpane.html

> How to use the javafx.application.Platform.runLater method to set the divider position when your application launches. (This technique is necessary due to how the application starts up and initializes)